# WIFI Pentest methodology

Tags: wifi

I am looking for a comprehensive materials regarding WiFi security assessment methodology.

I checked the internet but there is no much info. I am more interested for a bigger/enterprise picture.

Where I should start and on which areas (step by step) I should focus when define the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good resource to get started. The author wrote about 14 articles around WiFi security and hacking. If you are looking for something more like a textbook, I haven't found a great resource that focuses on WiFi hacking.

[How to hack WiFi - Getting Started](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wi-fi-getting-started-with-terms-technologies-0147659/)

[List of all of the articles in the series](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/wi-fi-hacking/)

Answer (score 1):

The methodology utilized varies between protocols. I will give a slim rundown of a pentest methodology for each:

**WEP**

- Packet capture until 130,000+ Initialization vectors are captured.
- Replay these IV's in order to perform a fake authentication attack with the access point.

**WPA/WPA2**

- Attempt to capture the authentication handshake through deauthentication attacks
- Perform an offline dictionary-based attack against the PSK

To just learn about WIFI pentesting in general to gain an understanding on how to pentest it, I would begin by learning the differences between WEP, WPA, WPA2 and variants. Within this process you will learn about the authentication mechanisms utilized by each protocol. You should gain an understanding of how WIFI works as a whole as well. This includes the different channels, the frequency, and how clients authenticate / deauthenticate from their wireless network, and packet capturing. Wireshark will be great for viewing the protocol in action.

To setup a lab for testing, all you will need is an internet connection, any cheap router and a wireless card capable of packet injection. For software, I prefer the Airocrack-ng suite running on Linux but really whatever tool you understand the best will work the best. (Reaver, Wifite and others definitely deserve a mention).

A great resource for this would be airocrack-ng's tutorials and tool suites, found here:

https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=getting_started

https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=simple_wep_crack

https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5415